# Java Date Class NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am trying to set and return the earliest date from a string and I think I am missing something when setting my date as I keep getting a nullreferenceexception whenever I try to set the values for Date.  Thanks for any help

```
private static Date createDate(String input)
{
    Date date = null;

    if (input == null)
        return null;

    // Split formatted input into separate values
    String tempDates[] = input.split(dateSep);

    // Store values as integers
    int[] dateValues = {0, 0, 0};
    dateValues[0] = Integer.parseInt(tempDates[0]);
    dateValues[1] = Integer.parseInt(tempDates[1]);
    dateValues[2] = Integer.parseInt(tempDates[2]);

    // Sort integers from lowest to highest
    Arrays.sort(dateValues);

    // Set return date
    date.setMonth(dateValues[0]);
    date.setDate(dateValues[1]);
    date.setYear(dateValues[2]);


    System.out.println(date);
    // Checking basic date restrictions
    if (date.getMonth() <= 0 || date.getMonth() > 12)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Month is not valid " + month);

    if (date.getDay() <= 0 || date.getDay() > 31)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Day is not valid " + day);

    if (date.getYear() <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Year is not valid " + year);


    return date;
}

}
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `date` before using it. You've only declared it and assigned it a `null` reference.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Technically he has initialized it in addition to declaring it, but he's initialized it to `null`.

Comment: @arshajii (Nitpicking) Is that called initializing or just setting a reference?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it is initialized with `null` value, it is not the same as just declare the variable `Date date;`.

Comment: Why are you sorting the `dateValues` array?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Aha, there's the distinction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `Date` object.
Change this line to `Date date = null;` to `Date date = new Date();`.

Normally you will get [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

> When you attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:
>   1.Calling the instance method of a null object.
>   2.Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
>   3.Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
>   4.Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
>   5.Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `Date date = null;`

you initialized with `null`.

and doing operation on `null`.

what you have to do is

```
date = ..evaluate value here....
```

or as others mentioned,Assign `new Date()` to it and do something.

```
 date.setMonth(dateValues[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the variable `date`. 
To have a look at initializing it, have a look at the following post: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

```
date = new Date();
```

or

```
//The following constructor accepts one argument that equals the number of milliseconds that // have elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970
date = new Date(long millisec);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As all the other answers state, you need to initialize *date*, otherwise you will always get a null pointer/reference exception:

```
     date = new Date()
```

Furthermore, sorting the array does not make ensure a Month/Day/Year format as expected with your code:

```
    date.setMonth(dateValues[0]);
    date.setDate(dateValues[1]);
    date.setYear(dateValues[2]);
```

Even though I understand you want to retrieve the earliest date from the string, it is better if you validate these restrictions directly with *tempDate*